# uMatrix: disabling 1st party script and plugins

Tags: umatrix

I am replacing NoScript with uMatrix.

I like the idea that every random site I happen to reach will not run any script or plugins, like noScript provided.

But the default for uMatrix is to always allow first-party scripts and even plugins! I can't find any setting to disable it. The closest I got was a screen to save "temporary rules". But I want this to be permanent and for everything!

Is there a way without forking?

Comment: "Plugin" tab has been removed and replaced with "media": https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/releases/tag/1.0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read "[walkthrough for first time users](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/wiki/Very-bare-walkthrough-for-first-time-users)" in [uMatrix wiki](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/wiki).

You have to toggle scope (top-left corner), `*` icon indicates global rules. Now disable "plugin" (the column has been removed in [uMatrix 1.0.0](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/releases/tag/1.0.0)) and "script" in the "all" row (cookies and frames are disabled in the image) and press save (the padlock icon). Make sure that "1st-party" isn't allowed (bright green box, in the image first-party frames are allowed).

[image]

Comment: omg. a down arrow there would make wonders. I ended up figuring out how to go to settings, manually editing the rules, and committing them to save. And all that was more obvious that this top rectangle (that looks like every other toggle button) was a drop down :)